# How to migrate mysql authentication from mysql_native_password to caching_sha2_password?

Tags: java, mysql, linux

So far I'm only using `mysql_native_password` authentication, either from `java` applications or bash scripts as follows.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootpw
```

Or native bash scripts:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=rootpw; mysql --user=root --database=mytable -e "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(...)"
```

Question: how can I migrate those applications for `caching_sha2_password`, but still being able to authenticate the applications with username/password combination as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all open your MySQL configuration, which is `my.cnf` or `my.ini`, then under `[mysqld]` section write like below:

```
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password
```

now go to MySQL server using the root account and write this SQL command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'root_password';
```

and in your Spring Boot and `application.properties` enter like this:

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root_password
```

at the end for native bash scripts, just use the `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable!

something like this:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=rootpw; mysql --user=root --database=mytable -e "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(...)"
```

Comment: So at the end I basically only have to change the authentication plugin for my existing users with the `ALTER USER` statement, and the applications don't have to be modified?

Comment: yes you only need to update the authentication plugin for your existing users using the `ALTER USER` statement, and the applications can continue to authenticate with the MySQL server using the username/password combination without any modifications!